# Keep foreach loop variable value inside html I tag is not working

Tags: php, html, laravel

i am trying to keep foreach loop variable value inside i tag class..

```
    @foreach($assignment_operators  as $assign_operator )
       <div style="font-size: 48px;color: white;">{{$assign_operator->ao_code}} </div>
@endforeach
```

[image]
i am getting the value like `

instead of this i am trying to get the image(x) of that i tag class..`

How can i get that i font class.

if i make outside of the foreach i am getting image properly..where did i miss it..please some one help me..

Comment: your question is quite unclear. can't see any i tag inside your foreach loop. update your question with things you have tried and expected output.

Comment: i already have value like this <i class="fas fa-times"></i> in my db table column (ao_code)..so  i just got that value

Comment: please check my updated question have added image.

Comment: try `{!! $assign_operator->ao_code !!}` as it is html